# Does 'upon' really mean 'on'?

Tags: prepositions

Many dictionaries say that 'upon' means 'on', for example:

- [Oxford Learners Dictionaries' definition of "upon"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upon?q=upon)
- [Cambridge Dictionary's definition of "upon"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upon)
- [Wiktionary's definition of "upon"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upon)

Does this work for all the meanings of *on*?

- *a book upon history* (*a book on history*)
- *see you upon Sunday* (*see you on Sunday*)
- *play upon a violin* (*play on a violin*)

Comment: The usage [*a book **upon** {subject matter}*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+book+on+American%2Ca+book+upon+American&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) was occasionally (not often) used a century ago, but rarely today. And I suggest *I'll see you **upon** Sunday* was *never* a natural usage. But [*playing **upon** the piano*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+upon+the+piano%2Cplayed+on+the+piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) sounds fine to me, even though it's far less common than it once was.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I was a kid there was a character in a rhyme called Aiken Drum, who played upon a ladle, an odd choice of instrument.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd argue that "play upon [instrument]" is also archaic. Hamlet: "Call me what instrument you will, though you can fret me, yet you cannot play upon me." I couldn't imagine using it today.

Comment: @AndyBonner: I'd certainly accept that [*played **upon** the piano*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+upon+the+piano&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is "dated". But "archaic" is *way* too strong! It was only by way of defending a *possible* usage, though. I certainly wouldn't recommend learners copying it. But I found only a single instance of [*never **upon** a Sunday*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22never+upon+a+sunday%22) in Google Books - from a Caribbean writer whose English looks *slightly* "odd" in many other ways anyway.

Comment: While upon is generally archaic and can mostly be replaced by "on", there are a few set expressions where you absolutely couldn't use "on".  For example: to come upon [someone/something].  That would be a real faux-pas!   Also: Once upon a time doesn't work with "on".

Answer (score 1):

Saying, “*Upon* means on” does not mean that *upon* can serve as a substitute wherever one encounters *on*. In fact, what it does mean is closer to the inverse: *On* can serve as a substitute wherever one encounters *upon*.

Here’s a parallel. In slang from the 1950s and 60s, *dig* can mean either enjoy or understand. So when that slang term is used, it can be replaced by one or the other of *enjoy* or *understand* (with the choice of which one depending on context) as in

> Hey, thanks for the gift; I really **dig** it,

and

> You **dig** what I’m sayin’?

respectively. But there are usages of, for example, *understand* where *dig* would not be an acceptable substitute, like *I **understand** some Spanish* and *I **understand** that your sister recently got married.*

Comment: Hey man, find a hep enough cat and I think they might just dig anything, from Spanish to marriage! But maybe the reverse is a better example: you can't always substitute "understand" for "dig." The OPs problem is that "on" is one of those words with a lot of non-interchangeable usages; "understand" has few.

Comment: Actually, @AndyBonner, my contention is that you **can** always substitute one or the other of *enjoy* and *understand* for the slang *dig* but not vice versa. And if some cat said, “I dig Spanish,” it would be interpreted to mean that he enjoyed it, liked it, not that he understood it. Furthermore, \**I dig some Spanish* doesn’t work at all.